# TortoiseGit - launch repobrowser command produces "no working directory found"

Tags: tortoisegit

From the command line I am attempting to open the repobrowser by using the following command:

```
TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:repobrowser
```

Once the command is executed a dialog displaying "No working directory found." is displayed.  I have even tried pointing to where I think the repo is by the following:

```
TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:repobrowser /path:"http://domain.here.com/" /notempfile
```

This produces the same error.  I have done something similar using TortoiseSVN which brings up a URL dialog box.

I have looked in the settings to see if a path may be set for temporary files, but I didn't find any.  Why is this error happening and how do I correct it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With (Tortoise)Git it is not possible view a remote repository in the repository browser w/o cloning it first.

`TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:repobrowser` w/o the `/path:` parameter only works if the current directory is a working tree or (bare) local repository.